# SQL Total of only the most recent record

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm trying to get a list of all persons with a total_pay_amt > 2000.  I need to include only the most recent sched_pymt_amt which is determined by sched_pymt_amt_eff_dt for each loan in this total. The code below gives me almost what I need except "having sum(sched_pymt_amt) > 2000" includes every sched_pymt_amt and not just the the most recent sched_pymt_amt_eff_dt. How do I limit my results to only sched_pymt_amt > 2000 using only the most recent sched_pymt_amt_eff_dt?

```
select 
    person_id, sum(sched_pymt_amt) as total_pay_amt
from
    (select 
         p.person_id, lp.loan_id, lp.sched_pymt_amt, lp.sched_pymt_amt_eff_dt, 
         row_number() over (partition by l.loan_id order by sched_pymt_amt_eff_dt desc) rn
     from
         person p 
     inner join
         loan_dtl l on p.person_id = l.brwr_person_id 
     inner join
         loan_repymt_plan lp ON l.loan_id = lp.loan_id
     where 
         1 = 1) a
where 
    rn = 1
having 
    sum(sched_pymt_amt) > 2000 --this is the problem line
group by 
    person_id
```

Comment: The problem isn't well defined yet, from what I can see the RN=1 should be limiting to only the most recent row payment per loan.  so I can't see why it would be including every scheduled payment.  I'd run the inner select by itself and look to see why you're getting multiple RN=1 for a given loan.  My guess is: your row number needs to be partitioned by personID and loan ID.  It may be loan ID isn't unique across all records.

Comment: You really should make a [mre] to demonstrate the data you're dealing, corner cases to deal with, where your query fails, what results you actually want, etc, etc.  It may be as simple as changing `WHERE rn=1` by adding `AND sched_pymt_amt > 2000` instead of the `HAVING` clause. But, without a working example your description is to vague and ambiguous. [mre] exists and is recommended in all cases for a reason; [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: It ended up being a problem not related to the code. It was counting payment amounts for loans with a $0 balance so I just filtered those out and it works. Point well taken on producing a minimal reproducible sample @MatBailie. I will do that next time with these instructions. Thanks

Comment: Not that it matters at this point but there are no "counts" in this. So problem not well defined.  I assume something else was counting totals and since 0 was an amount... issue arose.  but quesiton withrdawn I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you reduce the inner query to just the 1 table required. Use the `rn=1` as a join condition to this subquery. Also, move the having clause to after the group by clause. I also suggest doing a count of the loans because a person could have more than 1.

```
SELECT
      p.person_id
    , sum(lp.sched_pymt_amt) AS total_pay_amt
    , count(distinct lp.loan_id) AS num_loans
FROM person p
INNER JOIN loan_dtl l ON p.person_id = l.brwr_person_id
INNER JOIN  (
            select
                  loan_id
                , sched_pymt_amt
                , row_number() OVER (
                    PARTITION BY loan_id 
                    ORDER BY sched_pymt_amt_eff_dt DESC
                    ) rn
            from loan_repymt_plan
        ) lp ON l.loan_id = lp.loan_id AND lp.rn = 1
-- where there is more then 0 to pay, details unknown
GROUP BY
      p.person_id
HAVING sum(lp.sched_pymt_amt) > 2000 --"having" occurs AFTER group by
```